# Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150 shows a wrong path, I can't use the graphics debugging in vs2019

Tags: visual-studio, direct3d11

Well, I used to install visual studio in Disc D, and now I have moved it to Disc C, and deleted Disc D.

However, when I use services.msc to see the "Visual Studio Standard Collector Service 150", it seems still in Disc D?!

And I cannot even find the folder "DiagnosticsHub.Collection.Service", and I think that's the reason that I cannot use the Visual Studio Graphics debugging.

What can I do?